# How to send ESC Controls to Microsoft.PointOfService Emulator

Tags: opos, pos-for-.net

The following are the ESC codes for Micrsoft.PointOfService printers:

```
  string escAlignCenter = String.Format("{0}|cA", ((char)27));
  string escAlignRight = String.Format("{0}|rA", ((char)27));
  string escBoldOn = String.Format("{0}|bC", ((char)27));
  string escNewLine = String.Format("{0}|1lF", ((char)27));
  string escPaperCut = String.Format("{0}{1}|P", ((char)27), AppSettings.POSPrinterLinesToCut);
  string escReset = String.Format("{0}|N", ((char)27));
  string escUnderlineOn = String.Format("{0}|uC", ((char)27));
```

This code

```
simulatedReceipt.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}{1}Header will appear Here{2}",  escBoldOn, escAlignCenter, escReset));
```

when sent to the simulator printer with

```
 textToPrint = simulatedReceipt.ToString();
 posPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, textToPrint);
```

results in:

```
  System.FormatException occurred
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
 at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulatorWindow.ProcessEscapes(String str)
       at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulatorWindow.DisplayText(String str)
       at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulator.PrintNormalImpl(PrinterStation station, PrinterState printerState, String data)
       at Microsoft.PointOfService.BaseServiceObjects.PosPrinterBase.OutputRequestHandler(OutputRequest Request)
       at Microsoft.PointOfService.Internal.PosCommonInternal.ProcessOutputRequest(OutputRequest request, Boolean asyncOperation)
       at MyCourts.PrintReceiptManager.printToPOSPrinter() in e:\MyCourts\MyCourts\Managers\PrintReceiptManager.cs:line 558
  InnerException:
```

Unfortunately I don't have an appropriate receipt printer to test it on but I suspect the error only occurs with the built-in thermal printer simulator.

Can anyone confirm my suspicions please.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the SDK examples it is apparent that control codes are removed prior to sending to the simulator so it appears that the simulator will not simulate BOLD etc.